# Proving $ f (z)=5$ for all $ z \in \mathbb {C} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $ f: B \to \mathbb {C} $ is analytic on the disk $ B= \{  z \in \mathbb {C} : |z|<2 \}$, that $f (1)=5$, and that $ f (w)=f (w/2)$ for every $ w \in \mathbb{B} $. Show that $ f (z)=5$ for all $ z $ in $ \mathbb {B} $

My general idea here is to prove that the function f (z) is bounded in $\mathbb {C} $ then invoke Liovilles theorem. I basically saying that $f (z)=5 $implies that the real part of $ f $ is equal to 5 which implies |e^f|=e^5. Therefore by Liovilles theorem, $e^f$ is constant,  taking log of both sides,$ f (z)=5$. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not trying to rub salt in the wound, but maybe you'd like to get more commentary on your proposed argument. First, you don't know whether $f$ is even defined on all of $\mathbb C$, so you can't really use Liouville's theorem.  All you know is that $f$ is defined on the disk $|z| < 2$.  Further, $f(z) = 5$ is the conclusion you want to reach.  You can't assume $f(z) = 5$ for all $z$ in order to prove that $f(z) = 5$ for all $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So I take it my way is not the correct approach"

Your approach CAN work. $f$ is bounded and analytic on compact $\bar{D} = {z: |z| \leq 2 - \epsilon}$. You can define a new function $g$ such that $g(z) = f(z)$ when $z \in  \bar{D}$, and $g(z) = f(z/2^n)$ when $z \notin \bar{D}$.

Then prove that this $g$ is entire and bounded, and apply Liouville's Theorem.

Answer (score 4):

in fact all you need is continuity at $0$. take any $z$ in $B$, then $\frac{z}{2^n} \rightarrow 0$. iterating the identity from the question you get $f(\frac{z}{2^n} = f(z)$. if $f$ is continuous at $0$ then the left hand side converges to $f(0)$ hence $f(0) = f(z)$ for all $z$

Comment: This is a good way as well. +1

Comment: right, althought it looks like a homework problem so I suppose yours is the way they're looking for since mine doesn't really use any analytic functions theory, cheers

Comment: It was an exam question that I took today. That's the proof I wrote. is it wrong tho?

Comment: I don't really see how you arrive to apply Liouville's theorem. you don't mention the $f(z) = f(z/2)$ in what you wrote

Comment: Yes I noticed that but does that condition really change the proof? Because no matter what f (z) is, it will be constant.

Comment: if you don't use the fact that $f(z) = f(z/2)$ then it can't be right. take $f(z) = 5z$

Comment: there goes 20 points

Answer (score 3):

The way I would do this is to consider the function $g(z) = f(z)-5$. Then $g$ has an accumulation point of zeroes in the ball. (What is the set of zeroes and what is the accumulation point?) What would you know then about $g$ and hence about $f$ from this observation?

Comment: Identity theorem?

Comment: Precisely. What would that tell you?

Comment: Sorry I meant that I don't have that theorem in my complex analysis course

Comment: Oh. You'll cover it soon, then. I do not think your proof-as written-is correct, though. I think it can be salvaged but it'll be some marriage of your proof with @mm-aops.

Comment: There goes 20 points then lol.

Comment: You're on the right track but I think you need to argue that $e^f$ is bounded by way of the condition $f(z) = f(z/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is bounded and analytic on compact $D= \{z: |z| \leq 1\}$. By the maximum modulus principle, $|f|$ attains a maximum on the boundary, say $M = |f(e^{i\theta})| \geq |f(z)|$ for all $z \in D$.  But then $|f(e^{i\theta}/2)| = |f(e^{i\theta})|=M$. So $f$ attains it's maximum at an interior point and thus by the maximum modulus principle must be constant.

Comment: I really like this problem. Several logically distinct answers that are all valid.

Comment: So I take it my way is not the correct approach